# Seeing "large fonts" on websites in all browsers

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I would like to ask something about what happened with my Web Browsers. I'm an avid web surfer btw. I didn't know when it started but some of the websites I'm visiting started to have larger fonts than usual. Here is a screengrab of a website called screenrant.

[image: website]

As you can see, the items (Reviews, Podcasts, etc.) overlapped to the bar. I thought it was just a Chrome thing because they notified they were changing something in the coming updates (something about HTML5) but when I went to use IE11 it was also like this.

Please note that it was not bad internet connection that was causing this, because not all websites are having this bug.

Comment: If you see these large fonts in all browsers then this suggests there is a setting on your computer (perhaps to do with "Accessibility") that has changed. FWIW I cannot reproduce the "large fonts" on the website in your screenshot with default browser settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with different browsers. For the Google browser install Stylish addon and Google search - Classic Links userstyle then restart browser. Also, go to Firefox/ Options/ Content and reset the default settings. Click on Advanced and change the Minimum font size value to None. Make sure the Allow pages to choose their own fonts box is checked. For more help visit this page: [font-face-rendering-problem-in-chrome-and-firefox-use-postscript-outlines](http://blog.wax-o.com/2012/11/font-face-rendering-problem-in-browsers-use-postscript-outlines/)

Comment: Also, go to Firefox/ Options/ Content and reset the default settings. Click on Advanced and change the Minimum font size value to None. .. i think this is exactly the same thing w3d is saying only that its IE. I was offering help across the board be it any browser i hope you visited the blog i posted.